# No redstone fast elevator in minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm on a prison server where there is no redstone. I need an elevator for my building. What is a fast non-redstone elevator? I need to be able to stop at any floor easily, and I don't want it to be a hassle to use. Thanks.

Comment: Redstone is the core component for moving pistons and the like. Unless you do a minecart elevator, there isn't really another way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you want is probably a simple Minecart elevator, as shown by Monkeyfarm in this rather old video:

Start on the bottom floor. Place a single ladder 5 blocks up against a wall. Go up and place blocks (I recommend bottom half-slabs) around the block *above* the ladder. Now place a block, a rail and a Minecart on top of the ladder, and break the cart.

Repeat this pattern with a distance of 4 blocks. To get up, stand below the Minecart, look up, and hold right-click, teleporting from cart to cart. To get down, simply jump. To get out on any floor, face the wall the ladder is on and hold forward, while exiting your Minecart. You should land on the ladder holding the Minecart, and can walk/jump out easily.

Comment: Thank you, the old method still works! It's extremely fast, and I'm using it for a large apartment building. Because it uses a lot of iron and I'm on a prisons server it was no hassle to get the resources, I'll reward you the bounty later today!

Answer (score 4):

What I would suggest is the **Boat Elevator**.  Since wood is usually really easy to acquire and works nearly the same way minecarts do in terms of riding ability.

This video explains how this concept works

Basically if you have a boat underwater and you click on it, it will push you back onto the nearest land, but if you remove the land nearby and only leave the block you want it to push you onto then it can push you upwards.

Here is a picture for reference:
The glass ground is there because they also can't push you onto glass[image]